# bootstrap 3 datepicker disable minutes like reservation form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I would like to use [bootstrap 3 datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates) in reservation form. I found how to disable dates (m/d/Y) but i cannot disable a time.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                    defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                    disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2013"),
                        new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                        "11/22/2013 00:53"
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to disable only `11/22/2013 00:53` and not all day `11/22/2013`.

I also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mfjvnh9a/), which disable minutes 00 but if you choose 16:00 you cannot change it to 16:15.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to disable the entire time field or just the minute filed?

Comment: i want to disable ONLY minute 53 in minute field at 11/22/2013 00:53

Comment: so, any other minute is fine but it should not be 53, is that what you mean?

Comment: YES any other minute between 00:00 and 01:00 is fine

Comment: you probably would require javascript to check and update the minute field. else create your own dropdown/plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a loooong time, i had to use bootstrap datetimepicker on existing project. So i found `stepping` option

```
stepping: 15
```

So here is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: one_month,
            minDate: new Date(),
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            stepping: 15
        });
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand what you need. From what I got, you want to change the minutes, but in stepps (5,10,15). For that you can use a similar approach of the link you passed, but without disabling the step selector.

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YY - HH:mm'
    }).on('dp.show', function () {
    $('a.btn[data-action="incrementMinutes"], a.btn[data-action="decrementMinutes"]').removeAttr('data-action').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/xwoejb)

But if you don't want to display minutes, only hours, you can simply change the [format of your timepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format). And can use some [naming conventions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) from [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). If your format is something like 'DD/MM/YY - HH' it will only show hours.

The con on that solution is that the selector gets weird, and you can't really know what you are picking. So the solution you provided on your link is the best way to inly pick hours.

Comment: i want to make a reservation for example 15 minutes between 2015/11/28 12:05 and 2015/11/28 12:20. So i want, user cannot choose 2015/11/28 12:05, 12:10 and 12:15